# Jasmine + Karma: 'expect' was used when there was no current spec error, but why?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jasmine, karma-runner

I am totally lost. When I run this test suit written with Jasmine in Karma, I get this error: **'expect' was used when there was no current spec, this could be because an asynchronous test timed out**

But why? This is a fully synchronous example.

```
describe('Controllers Autocomplete', () => {
  it('should inject the empty suggestions container', () => {
    let a = 1;
    let b = 2;
    expect(a).toNotEqual(b);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Finally, solved it!

Folks, never do this...
**Karma.config.js file:**

```
config.set({
    // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
    basePath: '',

    // frameworks to use
    // available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
    frameworks: ['**mocha**', 'jasmine-jquery', '**jasmine**', 'browserify'],
```

Mocha and Jasmine are both test frameworks, and both share very similar syntax. So I was thinking I am using Jasmine, but was in fact using Mocha... just stick to one.